# Finding the angle of elevation.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, angle

[image: Problem]

The angle of elevation of S from Q is 33 degrees. What is the angle of elevation of T from P?

I just had a math test today and I was doing pretty well until I come across this question. I need help from the experts on how should I approach this problem?

Update: A friend of mine manage to solve this. [image: Problem]

Is this valid based on our given information? If not, what would the question need to be for it to be valid.

Comment: Is it possible that you have made a typo, and the question is actually "What is the angle of elevation of $T$ from $Q$"? If not, could it be that some other piece of information is missing?

Comment: Literally what my reaction was. I live in Malaysia and I'm sometimes frustrated by how the questions are worded. This is verbatim.

Comment: Hey @EvanAad can you verify my friend's solution?

Comment: It is crucial that you figure out exactly what is meant by the ambiguous expressions "the angle of elevation of $S$ from $Q$", and "the angle of elevation of $T$ from $P$". Until you have a precise understanding of what these expressions mean in the context of this problem, there is no way to judge whether a certain suggested solution is correct. Do you have a textbook that uses the expression "an angle of elevation"? If so, can you scan and paste the part where this expression is defined?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. There is no material that I know of that uses this expression. This is how I interpret the question assuming if the question follows the normal definitions. http://puu.sh/rQl0g.jpg .

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't feel like I can help you with this problem any more than I already have. Good luck!

Comment: It's okay, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression "an angle of elevation of a point $A$ from a point $B$" is ambiguous. Therefore, in order to make sense of the problem, it must firstly be interpreted one way or another. In the context of this problem, I shall interpret the expression "the angle of elevation of $C$ from $Q$" as meaning the angle $\angle CPQ$, and I shall interpret the expression "the angle of elevation of $T$ from $P$" as meaning the angle $\angle TRP$.

Given these definitions, without further information the question is under-specified, and there is no way of determining the angle of elevation of $T$ from $P$. As an illustration, here are two diagrams based on the given data that show two different angles of elevation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was thinking of that as well. How could my friends manage to solve this without assuming? I guess they were faking it or something.

Comment: @Daniel McFluffy, Is your drawing in 3D?

Comment: Nah, it's not in 3D. It's 2D.